# ElementFromPoint for absolutely positioned elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-position, absolute

I'm using elementFromPoint to find which element to pass mouse events to after they are being captured by a ui mask.  I capture the event at the mask, hide the mask, then use elementFromPoint(event.pageX, event.pageY) to get the underlying element.

The problem is that elementFromPoint doesn't seem to work at all for absolutely positioned elements.  It just gives the first non-absolutely positioned parent.  Is there a way to get both absolutely and non-absolutely positioned elements, or do I just have to do a manual search through the absolutely positioned children once I get the parent with elementFromPoint?

Thanks

Comment: elementFromPoint should work for absolutely positionned elements. Could you provide a jsfiddle which reproduce your issue?

Comment: Hmm, so I just made a jsfiddle but everything works like I think it should.  Must be an unrelated error in my code somewhere :S  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Derp, I was using a point that was in relation to my viewport, not the pageX and pageY of the event (facepalm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried and created the code its working absolutely fine [have a look](http://jsfiddle.net/uC8Z5/)

html

```
<div id="one">1</div>
<div id="two">2</div>
<div id="three">3</div>
<div id="four">4</div>
<div id="five">5</div>
<div id="six">6</div>
```

css

```
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#five{
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 20px;
    background: red;
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
    $(document.body).bind('click', function(e){
        var elem = document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY);

        alert('you selected element id: ' + elem.id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My experience is regular old document.elementFromPoint(...) works for absolutely positioned elements too, **but** it's sensitive to the "order" of the elements (which element is *really* "in front"). I've found that sometimes to get it to work the way I want, I have to explicitly specfy the CSS "z-index" (sometimes with a positive value of 10 or more) on the absolutely positioned element.

This is especially an issue if the elements have no background and contain just text, as all  of them will be visible at the same time in the same place. From just the appearance, it can be hard to tell which one is really "in front", perhaps not the one you think.